# Android Library Project Java Files Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies, project

I have two versions of an android library, one is paid and one is free. Rather than having to keep copying code and resources between them, I created an Android Library Project.

I created the library project, marked it as a library, and then set my paid and free projects to use the library as a library.

I copied everything synonymous between the paid/free projects into the library project (source code, drawables, layouts, etc) and works great EXCEPT for the source files.

The src file in my library project holds my source code in a package called "(default package)" except my free/paid projects aren't finding the files. They claim that they don't exist, even though it can find other things from my library, such as the drawables and layouts.

I've tried cleaning all of the projects, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have an idea, or run into this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

A library project requires a package name. Re-factor the project by Right-clicking on the package -> Refactor -> Rename.

Using the default package is generally discouraged.